# Render waiting page while waiting for express JS to finish an asynchronous task

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

Ok, either this is so basic that it's dump or very complicated and not doable but I can't seem to find an answer after digging around for more than 3 hours. It's gotta be quite common and I'm just to fresh to find the solution...

The problem is simple, I am building an Node JS Express app and I want to display a waiting page (either a spinning disk or loading message) while I am fetching data from an API endpoint. I need to go server side (hence the use of express and node js) because of CORS problem with the endpoint API and the client when I try to use VUE for example (I don't control the API responses...).

I thought that the Express JS business logic would be simple, ie send some logic to the template engine to render some part of the layout while I'm waiting for the fetch to complete and once the fetch is done, re-render and send the client a fresh version with the data.

However, the way I implemented is not working. Here's the PUG index template with the logic to display a bootstrap spinning disk if `loading` is true while rendering the block **content** if not

**index.pug**

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    if title
      title= title
    else
      title Loading data!

    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='/bootstrap/bootstrap.css')

  body
  if loading
    div(class="text-center")
      div(class="spinner-border m-5" role="status")
        span(class='visually-hidden') Loading...
  else 
    div(class='container-fluid')
      div(class='row')
        div(class='col-sm-2')
          block sidebar

        div(class='col-sm-10')
          block content
```

I have a very simple index route pointing to a controller handling the business logic

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const data_controller = require("../controllers/dataControler")

/// data ROUTES ///
router.get("/", data_controller.index)

module.exports = router
```

and I thought that I would use a controller that render the initial page with `loading` set to `true`, then re-send the page once the `fetch()` as returned. However this is not working

**dataControler.js**

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

// INDEX handler for /  (home page)
exports.index = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  // render this inital view, setting loading to true
  res.render("index", {
    title: "Loading data",
    loading: true,
  })

  const data = await do_long_dataSyncing()

  res.render("index", {
    title: "Data is cooked!",
    loading: false,
    data: data,
  })
})

const do_long_dataSyncing = async () => {
  fetch('someEndpoint')
}
```

I tried using some stacked middleware with a `next('route')` call but got pretty much the same.

This gotta be pretty straight forward logic as this is really common but must be a neebie thing that is getting tough early... I'm guessing that I might be able to set some logic in the middleware and use a redirect but can't seem to get my brain around the problem...

Anyhow, looking for your feedback and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

> send some logic to the template engine to render some part of the layout while I'm waiting for the fetch to complete and once the fetch is done, re-render and send the client a fresh version with the data.

No, that's not how `res.render` works. In an express router handler, you handle a *single* http request and you can write only a *single* http response. You cannot re-render or send another version. `res.render()` does not "call the client" to (repeatably) render anything, it uses the template engine to render the data and then sends that result as the single response, ending the connection.

If you want to display some custom message while the data is loading, you need to send the page without the data, then load it in a second request. Go with your Vue client application, just don't call the external API directly from the client but call your own API to avoid the CORS issues. Your server can still act as a simple proxy to forward the request to the other API and send back its response.

Comment: Yeah... I think I'm slowly drinking your cool-aid... The VUE app would have to be on some sort of interval to probe the Express server for completion, dropping the reactive for a client/server poking... been slowly heading there trying to think about sending some JS to the client to trigger a new request while this would easily be handle by a VUE app... Ok.. it's brewing... What's kinda of cool whit this is that I don't have to fear timeouts or keep the connection alive while the jobs are running... cool cool...

Comment: Hmm... keep brewing that cool-aid! I probably don't have to probe, just set up a conditial v-if div while I'm waiting for the express server response... Same as when waiting for a CRUD API db call to return data... Ok!!! getting there!

Comment: OOOHHH!!! What's cool is I can even drop the templating/rendering on the express side and just send `res.json(data)`